# I want to put a middle mark in a range in html 5 in angular

Tags: html, angular, sass, angular-material, range

I have a problem adding a middle mark just to show where is the middle in the range.
Here is an example of what i want to make: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ySnb.png.

And here is my code and what i'd get.

html:

```
   <div class="col-2">
       <div class="mt-3 text-center body-2 colorP6 fw-500" data-cy="title">
           {{title}}:
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class=" col-10">
       <div class="row mb-4">
           <div class="col me-6">
               <b class="text-center body-3" [ngClass]="{
                   'colorT4' : mark > 0,
                   'colorP6' : mark <= 0 
                }">{{subtitle}}</b>
           </div>
           <div class="col mr-5">
               <b class="text-center body-3" [ngClass]="{
                   'colorT4' : mark < 0,
                   'colorP6' : mark >= 0
                }">{{subtitle2}}</b>
           </div>
       </div>
       <div class="row ms-4">
           <input type="range" class="slider" min=-100 max=100 value={{mark}} data-cy="mark">
       </div>
   </div>
</div>

.sass:
@use 'colors'

.colorP6
   color: colors.$primary06

.colorT4
   color: colors.$tertiary04



.slider
   -webkit-appearance: none
   width: 51%
   height: 0.25rem
   background: #CFCBC7
   outline: none
   border-radius: 0.5rem

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb
   -webkit-appearance: none
   appearance: none
   width: 0.9375rem
   height: 1.6875rem
   background: #8DCB80
   cursor: pointer
   border-radius: 0.25rem

.slider::-moz-range-thumb
   width: 1.25rem
   height: 3.75rem
   background: #8DCB80
   cursor: pointer
   border: 0.3125rem solid lawngreen
   border-radius: 0.25rem

.slider::-ms-range-thumb
   width: 1.25rem
   height: 3.75rem
   background: #8DCB80
   cursor: pointer
   border: 0.3125rem solid lawngreen
   border-radius: 0.25rem
.tickmark
   -webkit-appearance: none
   appearance: none
   width: 0.9375rem
   height: 1.6875rem
   color: #8DCB80
   cursor: pointer
   border-radius: 0.25rem
```

Image of the component: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNaUH.png

I tried to put a datalist in the range but the only thing that makes is move the thumb down and the marks didn't appear.

Comment: it's only in .ts write "mark=0". NOTE: If you want to "store in the variable "mark" the value of slider use `[(ngModel)]` (not value): `<input type="range" [(ngModel)]="mark" ...>`

Comment: That thing its right, i want a marker that have a value that change its position(the thumb) and also a middle marker that is in the middle.